# Passing variable data between blocks in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Twig:

```
{% set var = 'apple' %}

{% block A %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple #}
{% endblock %}

{% block B %}
    {% set var = 'banana' %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints banana #}
{% endblock %}

{% block C %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple, but I want it to print banana #}
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any way to get the changed value from block B in block C?

Comment: e.g. In PHP i can do: `$var= 0;if(true){$var =2;}echo $var; # value == 2 not 0`

Comment: Twig blocks have their own scope. So if you want block C to print `banana`, you have to override `var` outside block B.

Comment: Also, have a look at the `with` keyword in twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/with.html

Comment: @mickdev I want the changed value from Block B in Block C i.e. banana. The actual issue I have is I have a {body block} in which I set the value and I want access to that new value in my {javascript block}.

Comment: @Jan I tried it earlier, But I suspect I might have missed something. Let me check and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hack it and set the value in your `$_SESSION` variable and access it in the required block:

```
{% set var = 'apple' %}

{% block A %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple #}
{% endblock %}

{% block B %}
    {% set var = 'banana' %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints banana #}
    {{ app.session.set('var', var) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block C  %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple #}
    {% set var = app.session.get('var') %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints banana #}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/zvx6ql) to show you.

Or In the comment section you mentioned that you want to access a variable in `{% block javascripts %}` which has been set in `{% block body %}`. You can hack it and move your `js` code in your body block. But I prefer to keep my `js` code in one place.

```
{% set var = 'apple' %}

{% block A %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple #}
{% endblock %}

{% set var = 'banana' %}
{% block B %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints banana #}
`<script>{{ var }}</script>` {# Bring your js code in the required block#}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This could solve the problem, but, please! stop putting everything into sessions and treating them as if the session were a global var.

I consider this a bad practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the set outside of the block like so:

```
{% set var = 'apple' %}

{% block A %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple #}
{% endblock %}

{% set var = 'banana' %}
{% block B %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints banana #}
{% endblock %}

{% block C %}
    {{ var }}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/zvx6ql) to show you.

Comment: I want the changed value from Block B in Block C i.e. banana.

The actual issue I have is I have a {body block} in which I set the value and I want access to that new value in my {javascript block}.